# adding an additional charge to shopping cart total using wp e-commerce

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I use wp e-commerce plugin to running my e-commerce wordpress powered site. I want to add an additional charge to shopping cart total as a subtotal but I dont know how to do it. I'm planning to use an insurance for every items I sold and it will be 10% of the single item price.

Is there anybody have tried this before? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add the insurance as part of the shipping costs:

1. Shipping A: standard
2. Shipping B: shipping with insurance

Comment: Did you meant using a multiple shipping method? Is it possible?